# Portando código Java para C++ ou Python

Tags: java, python, c++

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que foi originalmente escrito em Java.

Quero aprender mais sobre a matemática e a lógica por trás do código, e tive a ideia de portar o código pra outra linguagem.

Pensei em C++ e Python.

Qual delas possui mais similaridades e levaria menos tempo e esforço pra traduzir?

Comment: Sua pergunta é opinativa, porque vai da experiência e opinião pessoal de cada um. Uns falarão que C++ será melhor e outros dirão que é Python. Não há resposta clara porque isso depende de gosto e preferência pessoal. Além disso o tempo e o esforço dependem muito do tipo de aplicação de que se trata, da forma como está organizada, e também do seu conhecimento em C++ e em Python.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Não acho que seja um bom caminho para o que quer. Matemática e lógica se aprendem fora das linguagens de programação.

Java é considerada, bem grosso modo, uma evolução do C++ (posso te garantir que nenhum programador experiente de C++ acha isso), então em tese seria mais fácil traduzir para C++ do que Python, que não tem nenhuma semelhança com Java, a não ser pela semântica do `if` (nem a sintaxe) e mais alguma coisinha. Python tem uma filosofia absurdamente distante de Java.

Mas se quer algo semelhante ao Java deveria optar pelo C#. Essa sim é uma linguagem bem parecida e mais fácil. C++ é difícil para um iniciante que ainda está com dificuldade para entender a diferença básica entre linguagens.

Se não sabe nenhuma será difícil em qualquer uma. Aí a dificuldade é aprender a linguagem. Se tentar aprender durante a tradução, não conseguira nem uma coisa nem outra.

Qualquer pessoa dirá que Python é mais fácil de aprender que C++, mas isso quer dizer nada.

De qualquer forma precisa decidir se quer aprender algo ou se quer economizar tempo, essas coisas são incompatíveis (pelo menos no curto prazo, como descrito).

Qual você deve optar, eu não responderei, mas ressalto o caminho errado.